# How to have a character moved around the screen?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4

I already have a joystick programmed (finally) and I was wondering how I would get a 'hero' to move about the screen based on where the joystick is? I am using Cocos2d and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to subclass `CCNode` for your player object and then manipulate it as you would any other `CCNode`.  To start with, you can change the player's `position` struct like so:

```
player.position = ccp( player.position.x + [joystick xValue],
                       player.position.y + [joystick yValue]);
```

This is making some assumptions about how you want your joystick and player to behave, as well as some properties of the joystick class, but hopefully you get my drift.  If it isn't clear, `[joystick xValue]` and `[joystick yValue]` would be some bounded value (between -1 and 1, say) representing the touch's position on the joystick.  Depending on the range of values, you may want to then scale this by some constant to move the player faster or more slowly.

The cocos2d web site has a great [tutorial for beginners](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:index) that I'd highly recommend.  You might want to read up on the `CCAction` class as well for more complicated maneuvers.

Comment: It isn't a D-pad, it moves a lot like a video game controller does, just a touch screen :) Will your code still work if it is like this?

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect that.  If you have any questions, let me know!

Comment: Thanks spookyjon! Right now I am waiting for a friend to finish my player artwork, but I have made a stick figure while I've been waiting. I will test your code. It looks like it should work!

Comment: Oh, how do I subclass CCNode for my player. I'm extremely new to Cocos2d and a good explanation would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Where do I declare what these values are?

Comment: @spookyjon how do I determine the player.position.x and y?

Comment: @spookyjon OMH THANK YOU SOOOOOO MUCH!!!!!!!!!! I FINALLY GOT IT TO WORK THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!