# The best way to have a character moved around the screen with a joystick?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4

I am making a game. I would like to have a joystick that moves the character around the screen. Kinda like a video game controller. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Here is what I am currently using, guys. From looking at it, I don't think that it generates an input:

```
-(id) init
{


if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(255,255,255,255)] )) {
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase *leftJoy = [[[SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase alloc] init] autorelease];
    leftJoy.position = ccp(72,72);
    leftJoy.backgroundSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"dpad.png"];
    leftJoy.thumbSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"joystick.png"];
    leftJoy.joystick = [[SneakyJoystick alloc] initWithRect:CGRectMake(0,0,128,128)];
    leftJoyStick = [leftJoy.joystick retain];
    [self addChild:leftJoy];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setAnimationInterval:1.0f/60.0f];

}
return self;
```

}

Comment: On screen controls rarely make sense on the iDevices. A colleague of mine once proclaimed, "If your game depends on a d-pad and buttons, or joystick, you're doing it wrong." I quite think he's right. Don't limit yourself.

Comment: Yeah, but some of the most successful games have a joystick or something like that.

Comment: Joysticks make sense on a desktop where moving the entire screen or PC would be insane... just use the accelerometers and gyroscopes to turn the entire phone into a joystick.

Comment: No. I've already gotten this far. I have the joystick all programmed, I just want to have a character moved about the screen!!

Comment: This is merely my opinion, but adapting it to use inputs from the accelerometer and/or gyro wouldn't take a lot more effort, and would be a better user experience. Think of the itty bitty little users!

Comment: Is this different from your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359283/how-to-have-a-character-moved-around-the-screen

Comment: @spookyjon yes, i think that this is a different scenario.

Comment: You should post the code from the SneakyJoystick class, particularly anything dealing with the actual movement of the joystick during touch events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `direction` and `speed` from the `vector` produced by the joystick. Usually, joystick input generates normalized 2d position whose x and y values are between -1 and 1. For example, Up is (0, 1.0), Right is (0, 1.0), Left is (-1.0, 0) and Down is (0, -1.0). Once you have this input vector, you can get the two values.

```
direction = normalize( input_vector );
speed = length( input_vector ) * SCALE_CONSTANT; 
// SCALE_CONSTANT is a custom value to get a  real speed.
```

1. Set your character's `look-at` vector (it is a normalized vector representing character's current direction)  to `direction`. If you want to rotate the character smoothly, do interpolation from the current `look-at` vector to `direction` in your update.
2. Update your character's `position` with the `speed`

   new_position = current_position + look-at * speed * time;

You can see there are two movements, rotating and forwarding. People usually set two different speed constants to control them. You can also do one at a time like rotating first and then forwarding. Good Luck! :)

[UPDATE]

Well, if you don't want to rotate it, you can just do step 2 with "direction" instead of "look-at". Also, you can produce "input vector" by subtracting the `center position` of the joystick from `the actual movement` (I assume this is a position from the joystick) and then, normalize it.

Comment: @young The problem is, I don't know if i have that input vector! My joystick just moves. I'm not sure that it generates its velocity and stuff like that..

Comment: you said "I have the joystick all programmed", what does that mean? how do you access the joystick from your program? how do you detect its input events?

Comment: @young I also don't want to rotate the character's rotation, (at least, not right now). All I want is the actual sprite to be moved to a different location smoothly.

Comment: I have the actual movement of the joystick when it is clicked, but I'm not sure it generates an input.

Comment: Would you like me to edit the question and post my code for the joystick?

Comment: @young that sounds great! But i'm a newbie to this stuff and I don't now how to do what your update said. Please help :)

Comment: I assume that your joystick is on the screen and it should have its  position and that's the center position I'm talking about. When you move your joystick, it should give you another position and that's the current position of joystick. With the two positions, you can produce a vector by subtracting one from another like this (currentX- centerX, currentY-centerY). Then, normalize it by dividing each component by the length of the vector.

Comment: Okay, where do I find the vector that it comes up with when I move it? And what is it (probably) going to be named?

Comment: Create a vector from two positions and normalize it as I explained earlier. Name it whatever you want.

Comment: oh. never mind. i FINALLY GOT IT TO WORK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!